# JavaFX FXML application wont start

Tags: java, javafx

I have problems creating and running a JavaFX FXML application in Netbeans. Im running Netbeans 8.1. Below is code and errormessages. I guess its something wrong with the way netbeans write the path:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

But I cant figure out in what way ...

**Main**

```
public class JavaFXApplication6 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

**FXML**

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication6.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**ErrorMessage**

```
ant -f /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/ExempelJavaFX1 -Djavac.includes=JavaFXTheNewBoston/Ex031fxml.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Drun.class=JavaFXTheNewBoston.Ex031fxml run-single
init:
Deleting: /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/ExempelJavaFX1/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/ExempelJavaFX1/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/ExempelJavaFX1/build/classes
compile-single:
run-single:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$49/589873731.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3201)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at JavaFXTheNewBoston.Ex031fxml.start(Ex031fxml.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/1759200495.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/340870931.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/861248623.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1530388690.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application JavaFXTheNewBoston.Ex031fxml
/Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/ExempelJavaFX1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/ExempelJavaFX1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Here is my folder layout:

[image]

UPDATE
Also got this shorter errormessage:

```
ant -f /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7 -Djavac.includes=javafxapplication7/JavaFXApplication7.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Drun.class=javafxapplication7.JavaFXApplication7 run-single
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/build
Updating property file: /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/build/classes
Created dir: /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/build/empty
Created dir: /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to /Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/build/classes
compile-single:
run-single:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMet/Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication7/nbproject/build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)
```

UPDATE - here is my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for --><!-- some examples of how to customize the build. --><!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) --><!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. --><project name="JavaFXApplication1" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project JavaFXApplication1.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <!--

    There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
    used for execution of your tasks. These targets are usually executed 
    before and after some main targets. Those of them relevant for JavaFX project are: 

      -pre-init:                 called before initialization of project properties
      -post-init:                called after initialization of project properties
      -pre-compile:              called before javac compilation
      -post-compile:             called after javac compilation
      -pre-compile-test:         called before javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -post-compile-test:        called after javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -pre-jfx-jar:              called before FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
      -post-jfx-jar:             called after FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
      -pre-jfx-deploy:           called before FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
      -post-jfx-deploy:          called after FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
      -pre-jfx-native:           called just after -pre-jfx-deploy if <fx:deploy> runs in native packaging mode
      -post-jfx-native:          called just after -post-jfx-deploy if <fx:deploy> runs in native packaging mode
      -post-clean:               called after cleaning build products

    (Targets beginning with '-' are not intended to be called on their own.)

    Example of inserting a HTML postprocessor after javaFX SDK deployment:

        <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
            <basename property="jfx.deployment.base" file="${jfx.deployment.jar}" suffix=".jar"/>
            <property name="jfx.deployment.html" location="${jfx.deployment.dir}${file.separator}${jfx.deployment.base}.html"/>
            <custompostprocess>
                <fileset dir="${jfx.deployment.html}"/>
            </custompostprocess>
        </target>

    Example of calling an Ant task from JavaFX SDK. Note that access to JavaFX SDK Ant tasks must be
    initialized; to ensure this is done add the dependence on -check-jfx-sdk-version target:

        <target name="-post-jfx-jar" depends="-check-jfx-sdk-version">
            <echo message="Calling jar task from JavaFX SDK"/>
            <fx:jar ...>
                ...
            </fx:jar>
        </target>

    For more details about JavaFX SDK Ant tasks go to
    http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm

    For list of available properties check the files
    nbproject/build-impl.xml and nbproject/jfx-impl.xml.

    -->
</project>
```

Comment: Please add new lines in the error message

Comment: The error message simply means that it can't find the FXML file, so the path is incorrect. With the path you currently have, it is expecting to find `FXMLDocument.fxml` in the same package as the `JavaFXApplication6` class. Can you [edit] your question to show your project layout.

Comment: I have now added an image of my folderlayout. Its strange because this is how netbeans builds it as default ...

Comment: What is strange is that it hasn't compiled your controller class, or deployed the FXML file. Probably you need to clean and rebuild the project from scratch (not sure how to do that in NetBeans).

Comment: In netbeans you can clean and rebuild by selecting "Clean and Build" by rightclick on your projectfolder. Nothing changed though ...

Comment: Then you probably have something misconfigured in the build process, that is preventing it from compiling everything and deploying the FXML file.

Comment: For example, in the compilation log, you can see it says "Compiling 1 source file to `/Users/MyAccount/NetBeansProjects/ExempelJavaFX1/build/classes`". However there are two source files (`JavaFXApplication6.java` and `FXMLDocumentController.java`). Under `build/classes`, you should see both class files as well as the FXML file in the `javafxapplication6` package.

Comment: "Then you probably have something misconfigured in the build process"

Weird. This is the default project when creating a JavaFx FXML application in Netbeans. 

I have no idea what to do actually. Any hint?

Comment: Your build process is handled by ant which is used by Netbeans. Can you add the `build.xml` to your question.

Comment: I have now added my build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to Clean and Build,
2. Run File

Comment: Not sure why/who down arrowed this answer. As it is correct?